# How to findMany() with nested array of objects using Prisma?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, mongodb, next.js, prisma

I am trying to create filters in my web application. This is the structure of my database and products (simplified). I want to use findMany() to go through and return all products that have "cheeks" within the placement array (would return the first product). Or return all products that have at least "cheeks" and "eyes" listed in the placement array (would return both products).

```
    [
      // product 1
      {
        "palette": [
          {
            "id": "mondodb ID xxx",
            "hexColor": "#e9b190",
            "name": "color name 1",
            "properties": {
              "blue": 0.5647,
              "placement": [
                "cheeks"
              ],
              "green": 0.6941,
              "red": 0.9137
            }
          },
          {
            "id": "mondodb ID xxx",
            "hexColor": "#fc9981",
            "name": "color name 2",
            "properties": {
              "blue": 0.5059,
              "placement": [
                "cheeks",
                "lips"
              ],
              "green": 0.6,
              "red": 0.9882
            }
          }
        ],
        "id": "mondo db id xxxx",
        "status": "APPROVE",
        "title": "Product title"
      },
      // product 2 
      {
        "palette": [
          {
            "id": "mondodb ID xxx",
            "hexColor": "#d67768",
            "name": "color name 3",
            "properties": {
              "blue": 0.4078,
              "placement": [
                "eyes"
              ],
              "green": 0.4667,
              "red": 0.8392
            }
          }
        ],
        "id": "mondo db id xxxx",
        "status": "APPROVE",
        "title": "Product title 2"
      }
    ]
```

This is my prisma schema:

```
model product {
  id            String @id @default(auto()) @map("_id") @db.ObjectId
  palette       ProductPalette[]
  status        Status @default(NEEDS_REVIEW)
  title         String
  @@unique([id, palette.id])
}

type ProductPalette {
  id                  String  @map("_id") @db.ObjectId
  hexColor            String?
  properties          Properties
  name                String
}

type Properties {
  blue                Float? @default(0)
  placement           Placement[]
  green               Float? @default(0)
  red                 Float? @default(0)
}

enum Placement {
  lips
  eyelid
  cheeks
}

enum Status {
  APPROVE
  NEEDS_REVIEW
  REMOVE_ITEM
}
```

I am having an issue with prisma's findMany() and constructing the correct "where" clause. I currently have this which will not work. This is a Next.js application with typescript and MongoDb.

```
        (await prisma?.product?.findMany({
          skip: ITEMS_PER_PAGE * (Number(page) - 1),
          take: ITEMS_PER_PAGE,
          orderBy: {
            createdDate: (orderBy as Prisma.SortOrder) ?? 'asc',
          },
          where: {
            palette: {
             some: {
              properties: {
                placement: [Placement.cheeks]
              }
             }
            }
          }
        }))
```

OS: macOS
Database: MongoDB
Node.js version: v20.8.1
Prisma version: 5.11.0